# Hilbert's Basis Theorem for countably infinitely many indeterminates

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It is well known that

> **Hilbert's Basis Theorem**. If ${\displaystyle R}$ is a Noetherian ring, then ${\displaystyle R[X]}$ is a Noetherian ring.
>
> **Corollary**. If ${\displaystyle R}$ is a Noetherian ring, then ${\displaystyle R[X_{1},\dotsc ,X_{n}]}$ is a Noetherian ring.

I am wondering if Hilbert's Basis Theorem can be extended to countably many indeterminates? For example, ${\displaystyle R[X_{1},\dotsc ,X_{n}, X_{n + 1}, \dotsc]}$ is also Noetherian. I would assume that induction is the way to go.

I am a little bit concerned about this  as I don't see it being mentioned on the Internet. So I suspect that something is wrong with this approach.

Comment: $R[x_1,x_2,...]$ is never Noetherian: $(x_1)\subsetneq (x_1,x_2)...$

Comment: @markvs would you care to record that below as an answer?

Comment: Induction on ℕ **never** produces "...". You're right to be concerned, but you should be **very** concerned. Each {1,...,n} has a maximum element, but {1,2,3,...} certainly does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R[x_1,x_2,...]$ is never Noetherian: $(x_1)\subsetneq (x_1,x_2)...$